# Email publisher in CruiseControl fails with no logging

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I've setup an Email publisher for my CruiseControl Version : 1.6.7981.1 project.

When I run the build, the only indication of an email error is this text "Failing Tasks : EmailPublisher" in the messages column in the Dashboard page.

There's no error messages in the server log or the build log.

This is the email pulisher :

```
<email
  from="flemming@xxx.dk"
  mailhost="mail.xxx.net"
  mailport="25"
  mailhostUsername="flemming@xxx.dk"
  mailhostPassword="xxxxxx"
  includeDetails="TRUE"
  useSSL="FALSE">
  <users>
    <user name="Flemming" group="buildmaster" address="flemming@xxx.eu" />
  </users>
  <groups>
    <group name="buildmaster">
      <notifications>
        <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
      </notifications>
    </group>
  </groups>
</email>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. McAfee virusscan blocks port 25 and 587 to prevent mail spamming from my server. Now I just need to figure out where to change the rules. Have a feeling it's my VPS provider I have to kick

Answer (score 0):

What else is in the publishers group?

IE:

```
<publishers>
  <xmllogger/>  <--- IMPORTANT  
   <email>
       yada
   </email> 
</publishers>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have the <xmllogger/> on. 
But I found the problem. McAfee virusscan blocks port 25 and 587 to prevent mail spamming from my server. Now I just need to figure out where to change the rules. Have a feeling it's my VPS provider I have to kick.

Comment: Some ISPs support using port 26 for email for this reason, might ask if yours does.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but high in the Google results for querying "ccnet email publisher failed task", so I'll add my 2 pence worth...

I ran CruiseControl.NET manually from the shortcut that is placed on the desktop (after stopping the service) and the console output included an exception, in bright red, which made it easy for me to figure out what was wrong:

> [Proj1:ERROR] Publisher threw exception: ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: EmailPublisher exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Turned out for me that I needed to set

```
useSSL="True"
```